# How can I get this image gallery right?

Tags: html, css

I found this code on internet about Image gallery, but when I'm writing a title that has more than 1 text line, the image that is above below the text goes far away and I don't understand why ?

Here's a screenshot of the issue I get : [image: issue]

here's my code :

```css
.item{
  margin-left: 25px;
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  float:left;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

img {
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#index-gallery{
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="index-gallery">
  <h2>NOS TESTS</h2>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">Forza 5 guide pour les nuls</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://movingimages.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/earth-simulator-offers-peaks-into-our-planetary-future.jpg?w=780" alt=""/>
    <p id="photo">My Caption here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to solve this is to set the height of the image container div.

```
.item{
  margin-left: 25px;
  width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  float:left;
  height: 335px;
}
```